# USB Device with Ingenico iCT220

Tags: c, usb, hid

**Short Story**

I have been tasked to connect an USB bar code scanner to this terminal [[linky (PDF)]](http://www.ingeserve.com/DataSheet/Technical+Manual+ICT220+EN+DIV1302A.pdf), it has an usb host port ("usb master" according to documentation) on which i can connect any usb device then using ingenico sdk's (C based) `systemfioctl's` functions i can detect if an usb device is present,read its PID, VID, Class, Sub Class and protocol,

**The problem...**

the only thing cannot do is read its input, i have tried with a mouse, keyboard and a joystic, according to documentation the OS creates a device file "com6" in order to interact with this usb port, the thing is that every time i `fread` this device it always reads 0 bytes, since this thing does not runs any version of linux i guess i cannot use conventional HID libraries.

does anyone ever had to do such a bizarre thing before?

Comment: Are you sure it's an hid device, not a communications class device?  Are you scanning a bar code first then reading?

Comment: Well the scanner that i got here report itself as an usb class 03 i suppose its an HID according to usb.org, gonna try another one =S

Comment: Hi @Harima555, I am currently working on iCT220. I have a similar situation now. I want to detect if PCLAN (COM5 or USB) cable is present/connected or not to the device (iCT220). I can open the port without even connecting the cable to the port. What I want to do is that I do not want to open-and-write into the COM5 if physical cable is not connected to the device. Have you done this before? If yes, then a small help would be very welcomed.

Comment: There is a config (in the device) to communicate on USB(COM) or USB-HID. First check your device config.  When you open a COM port, it will always seem to succeed (if the COM port exists in your OS). You can confirm it is a iCT220, by requesting info that only a iCT220 would acknowledge (health stat, system time, or equiv). If you get a valid response, then it is probably a iCT220.